# Вывод аватара по id ВКонтакте

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

кто-нибудь может дать объяснение как полноценно вывести аватар пользователя ВКонтакте по его id?

С vk.api у меня беда, но нужно исключительно только это. Надеюсь кто-нибудь выручит, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот примерно такой `json` вернется после отправки запроса `params[user_ids]=210700286&params[fields]=has_photo%2Cphoto_max%2Cphoto_id&params[name_case]=Nom&params[v]=5.103`:

```
{
"response": [{
"id": СПИСОК ID,
"first_name": "Lindsey",
"last_name": "Stirling",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true,
"photo_max": "https://sun1-94.u...jqcVSu9sI.jpg?ava=1",
"photo_id": "210700286_456240074",
"has_photo": 1
}]
}
```

Подробнее надо прочитать в [документации](https://vk.com/dev/users.get)

Есть **доступные значения** того, что передать: photo_id, verified, sex, bdate, city, country, home_town, has_photo, photo_50, photo_100, photo_200_orig, photo_200, photo_400_orig, photo_max, photo_max_orig, online, domain, has_mobile, contacts, site, education, universities, schools, status, last_seen, followers_count, common_count, occupation, nickname, relatives, relation, personal, connections, exports, activities, interests, music, movies, tv, books, games, about, quotes, can_post, can_see_all_posts, can_see_audio, can_write_private_message, can_send_friend_request, is_favorite, is_hidden_from_feed, timezone, screen_name, maiden_name, crop_photo, is_friend, friend_status, career, military, blacklisted, blacklisted_by_me, can_be_invited_group.

Более подробное описание каждого поля можно [прочитать тут](https://vk.com/dev/objects/user).

Answer (score 0):

Для этого используйте метод [`users.get`](https://vk.com/dev/users.get), который возвращает расширенную информацию о пользователях. Чтобы получить аватар пользователя, необходимо указать в параметр `user_ids` идентификатор пользователя (или их множество, через запятую; тогда в результате будет возвращен массив объектов данных пользователей), и в параметр `fields` значение `photo_200` (как вариант, там можно указать и другие типы, читайте документацию).

В качестве примера, можете использовать официальную библиотеку [`VK PHP SDK`](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-php-sdk) (или же любую другую). Чтобы самому не делать никаких велосипедов.